# How to add hyperlinks on google maps which zoom into the map?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, maps

I have a map which will be used on a website. However at the moment the only way I am able to zoom in and out is using the scrollbar or double clicking on the map but what I want is to have the name of places on the map and then for example when a user clicks on a country the map zooms in. So if anyone knows how to do this could someone please guide me. I have had a look on Google maps API but cannot find anything that meets my requirements.

Below is my code that I am currently:

```
var JP = JP || {};

(function() {
    var Map = function() {
        var self = this;

        this.map = null;
        this.mapCanvas = null;
        this.markers = [];
        this.mapOptions = {
            maxZoom: 9,
            minZoom:2,
            zoom: 3,
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(14.397, 30.644),
            scrollwheel: false,
            mapTypeControl: false,
            streetViewControl: false,
            zoomControlOptions: {
                position: google.maps.ControlPosition.LEFT_BOTTOM
            },
            panControlOptions: {
                position: google.maps.ControlPosition.LEFT_BOTTOM
            }
        }
        this.mapType = new google.maps.StyledMapType([
            {
                featureType: "all",
                elementType: "all",
                stylers: [
                    { visibility: "off" },  // Hide everything
                    { lightness: 100 }  // Makes the land white
                ]
            }, {
                featureType: "water",
                elementType: "geometry",
                stylers: [
                    { visibility: "on" },  // Show water, but no labels
                    { lightness: -9 },  // Must be < 0 to compensate for the "all" lightness
                    { saturation: -100 }
                ]
            }
        ]);
        this.overlay = null;

        this.init = function() {
            self.mapCanvas = $("#mapCanvas")[0];

            self.map = new google.maps.Map(self.mapCanvas, self.mapOptions);
            self.map.mapTypes.set('styledMapType', self.mapType);
            self.map.setMapTypeId('styledMapType');

            self.overlay = new google.maps.OverlayView();
            self.overlay.draw = function() {};
            self.overlay.setMap(self.map);

            // This is a stop-gap measure to minimize the effect of
            // a bug we haven't solved yet.

            google.maps.event.addListener(self.map, 'dragstart', function() {
                $(".message").not("#messageTemplate").remove();
            });
        }

        this.newMarker = function(lat, lng) {
            // Used for randomizing marker image
            var offset = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3) * 16;
            // Custom marker
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng),
                icon: new google.maps.MarkerImage(
                    'ideasforworldmap/static/img/map/dot.png',
                    new google.maps.Size(16, 16),
                    new google.maps.Point(0, offset),
                    new google.maps.Point(8, 8)
                )
            });

            return marker;
        }

        this.markLocations = function(locations) {
            var i = locations.length;
            while (i--) {
                var loc = locations[i];

                // Make new marker
                var marker = self.newMarker(loc.lat, loc.lng);
                self.markers.push(marker);

                // Tack on some extra data
                marker.message = loc;

                // Handle mouseover event
                google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseover', function() {

                    // Get screen xy
                    var pos = self.latLngPixel(this.getPosition());

                    // Create an overlay
                    var overlay = self.createOverlay( this.message, pos );

                    // Add it to the dom
                    $(self.mapCanvas).after(overlay);
                });

                // Stagger animation onto the map
                if (i < 50) {
                    marker.setAnimation(google.maps.Animation.DROP);
                    setTimeout((function(marker) {
                        return function() {
                            marker.setMap(self.map);
                        }
                    })(marker), i*200 + Math.random()*500+500);
                } else {
                    marker.setAnimation(null);
                    marker.setMap(self.map);
                }
            }
        }

        this.createOverlay = function(message, position) {

            var overlay = $("#messageTemplate").clone();

            overlay.attr("id", message.id);
            overlay.attr("href", "/ideasforworldmap/messages/"+ message.id +".html")

            // Position it at the marker
            overlay.css({
                left: position.x - 52,
                top: position.y - 52,
            });

            // Use distance from center to decide when to hide
            var radius = 50;
            var radiusSq = radius * radius;

            var checkDistance = function(event) {
                var dx = event.pageX - position.x;
                var dy = event.pageY - position.y;

                if( dx*dx + dy*dy > radiusSq ) {

                    $(window).unbind("mousemove", checkDistance);
                    overlay.data("MessageBubble").disappear(250);
                    setTimeout(function() {
                        overlay.remove();
                    }, 250);
                }
            }

            $(window).bind("mousemove", checkDistance);

            // Make it a message bubble
            overlay.messageBubble();

            var dom = overlay.data("MessageBubble").dom;
            dom.original.text( message.text );
            dom.translated.text( message.text_ja );
            dom.by.text( "By " + message.author );
            //dom.from.text( "From: " + message.location );

            if (dom.by.text() == "By " || dom.by.text() == "By Your name" || dom.by.text() == "By 名前（ローマ字)") {
                dom.by.text("");
            }

            if (dom.from.text() == "From: " || dom.from.text() == "From: Your location" || dom.from.text() == "From: 地名（ローマ字)") {
                dom.from.text("");
            }

            overlay.data("MessageBubble").disappear(0);
            setTimeout(function(){overlay.data("MessageBubble").appear(250);}, 20);

            return overlay;
        }

        this.latLngPixel = function(latLng) {
            var projection = self.overlay.getProjection();
            return projection.fromLatLngToContainerPixel(latLng);
        }
    }

    JP.map = new Map();
})();
```

Comment: You want an overlay on your map that will zoom to a country when it is clicked on?

Comment: @geocodezip yes an overlay but a text so for example it will say "UK"...when i click on uk it will zoom into that section of the map where the text "UK" was placed.

Comment: I would start from something like [this](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_GoogleEx_layer-kml_world_countries_simple.html), zoom to the country clicked on rather than opening an infowindow.

Comment: How would I go on to put it in my existing code? Do you have any ideas because with the map I have right now..I have markers which open up a infowindow which is fine..but I want text on the map which makes the map zoom in. @geocodezip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to add the country labels back onto the map, then zoom to the country clicked on.  Country border data from GeoJson.  Note that you will need to adjust some of the data as in this data set, French Guiana, which puts the geographic center of France (as one example) in the middle of the Atlantic ocean.

**Proof of concept code snippet:**

```js
var JP = JP || {};

(function() {
  function zoom2geometry(feature, map, info) {
    if (feature.getProperty('name') == "Antarctica") {
      return;
    }
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    if (feature.getGeometry().getType() == "Polygon") {
      var array = feature.getGeometry().getArray();
      for (var j = 0; j < array.length; j++) {
        for (var i = 0; i < array[j].getLength(); i++) {
          bounds.extend(array[j].getAt(i));
        }
      }
    } else if (feature.getGeometry().getType() == "MultiPolygon") {
      var array = feature.getGeometry().getArray();
      for (var k = 0; k < array.length; k++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < array[k].getLength(); j++) {
          for (var i = 0; i < array[k].getAt(j).getLength(); i++) {
            bounds.extend(array[k].getAt(j).getAt(i));
          }
        }
      }
    }
    map.fitBounds(bounds);
    // info.setContent(feature.getProperty("name_long"));
    // info.setPosition(bounds.getCenter());
    // info.open(map);

  }

  var Map = function() {
    var self = this;

    this.map = null;
    this.mapCanvas = null;
    this.markers = [];
    this.mapOptions = {
      maxZoom: 9,
      minZoom: 2,
      zoom: 3,
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(14.397, 30.644),
      scrollwheel: false,
      mapTypeControl: false,
      streetViewControl: false,
      zoomControlOptions: {
        position: google.maps.ControlPosition.LEFT_BOTTOM
      },
      panControlOptions: {
        position: google.maps.ControlPosition.LEFT_BOTTOM
      }
    };
    this.mapType = new google.maps.StyledMapType([{
      featureType: "all",
      elementType: "all",
      stylers: [{
          visibility: "off"
        }, // Hide everything
        {
          lightness: 100
        } // Makes the land white
      ]
    }, {
      featureType: "water",
      elementType: "geometry",
      stylers: [{
          visibility: "on"
        }, // Show water, but no labels
        {
          lightness: -9
        }, // Must be < 0 to compensate for the "all" lightness
        {
          saturation: -100
        }
      ]
    }, {
      featureType: "administrative.country",
      elementType: "labels.text",
      stylers: [{
        color: "#000000"
      }, {
        weight: 0.1
      }, {
        visibility: "on"
      }]
    }]);
    this.overlay = null;

    this.init = function() {
      self.mapCanvas = $("#mapCanvas")[0];

      self.map = new google.maps.Map(self.mapCanvas, self.mapOptions);
      self.map.mapTypes.set('styledMapType', self.mapType);
      self.map.setMapTypeId('styledMapType');

      self.map.data.setStyle(function(feature) {
        // Color each letter gray. Change the color when the isColorful property
        // is set to true.
        var color = 'gray';
        var opacity = 0.01;
        return { /** @type {google.maps.Data.StyleOptions} */
          fillColor: color,
          strokeColor: color,
          strokeWeight: 1,
          strokeOpacity: 0.1,
          fillOpacity: opacity
        };
      });

      self.map.data.overrideStyle(function(feature) {
        // Color each letter gray. Change the color when the isColorful property
        // is set to true.
        var color = 'gray';
        var opacity = 0.01;
        if (feature.getProperty('isColorful')) {
          color = "blue";
          opacity = 1.0;
          return { /** @type {google.maps.Data.StyleOptions} */
            fillColor: color,
            strokeColor: color,
            strokeWeight: 1,
            strokeOpacity: 0.1,
            fillOpacity: opacity
          };
        }
      });

      // When the user clicks, set 'isColorful', changing the color of the letters.
      self.map.data.addListener('click', function(event) {
        self.map.data.revertStyle();
        event.feature.setProperty('isColorful', true);
        // Color each letter gray. Change the color when the isColorful property
        // is set to true.
        var color = 'gray';
        var opacity = 0.01;
        var style = {};
        if (event.feature.getProperty('isColorful')) {
          color = "blue";
          opacity = 0.1;
        }
        style = { /** @type {google.maps.Data.StyleOptions} */
          fillColor: color,
          strokeColor: color,
          strokeWeight: 1,
          strokeOpacity: 0.1,
          fillOpacity: opacity
        };
        self.map.data.overrideStyle(event.feature, style);
      });

      self.map.data.loadGeoJson("https://api.myjson.com/bins/557lr");
      var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
      self.map.data.addListener("click", function(evt) {
        zoom2geometry(evt.feature, self.map, infowindow);
      });
      // When the user hovers, tempt them to click by outlining the letters.
      // Call revertStyle() to remove all overrides. This will use the style rules
      // defined in the function passed to setStyle()
      self.map.data.addListener('mouseover', function(event) {
        if (event.feature.getProperty('isColorful')) {
          return;
        }
        self.map.data.overrideStyle(event.feature, {
          strokeWeight: 8,
          fillColor: "red",
          fillOpacity: 0.1
        });
      });

      self.map.data.addListener('mouseout', function(event) {
        if (!event.feature.getProperty('isColorful')) {
          self.map.data.revertStyle(event.feature);
        }
      });
      self.overlay = new google.maps.OverlayView();
      self.overlay.draw = function() {};
      self.overlay.setMap(self.map);

      // This is a stop-gap measure to minimize the effect of
      // a bug we haven't solved yet.

      google.maps.event.addListener(self.map, 'dragstart', function() {
        $(".message").not("#messageTemplate").remove();
      });
    }

    this.newMarker = function(lat, lng) {
      // Used for randomizing marker image
      var offset = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3) * 16;
      // Custom marker
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng),
        icon: new google.maps.MarkerImage(
          'ideasforworldmap/static/img/map/dot.png',
          new google.maps.Size(16, 16),
          new google.maps.Point(0, offset),
          new google.maps.Point(8, 8))
      });

      return marker;
    }

    this.markLocations = function(locations) {
      var i = locations.length;
      while (i--) {
        var loc = locations[i];

        // Make new marker
        var marker = self.newMarker(loc.lat, loc.lng);
        self.markers.push(marker);

        // Tack on some extra data
        marker.message = loc;

        // Handle mouseover event
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseover', function() {

          // Get screen xy
          var pos = self.latLngPixel(this.getPosition());

          // Create an overlay
          var overlay = self.createOverlay(this.message, pos);

          // Add it to the dom
          $(self.mapCanvas).after(overlay);
        });

        // Stagger animation onto the map
        if (i < 50) {
          marker.setAnimation(google.maps.Animation.DROP);
          setTimeout((function(marker) {
            return function() {
              marker.setMap(self.map);
            }
          })(marker), i * 200 + Math.random() * 500 + 500);
        } else {
          marker.setAnimation(null);
          marker.setMap(self.map);
        }
      }
    }

    this.createOverlay = function(message, position) {

      var overlay = $("#messageTemplate").clone();

      overlay.attr("id", message.id);
      overlay.attr("href", "/ideasforworldmap/messages/" + message.id + ".html")

      // Position it at the marker
      overlay.css({
        left: position.x - 52,
        top: position.y - 52,
      });

      // Use distance from center to decide when to hide
      var radius = 50;
      var radiusSq = radius * radius;

      var checkDistance = function(event) {
        var dx = event.pageX - position.x;
        var dy = event.pageY - position.y;

        if (dx * dx + dy * dy > radiusSq) {

          $(window).unbind("mousemove", checkDistance);
          overlay.data("MessageBubble").disappear(250);
          setTimeout(function() {
            overlay.remove();
          }, 250);
        }
      }

      $(window).bind("mousemove", checkDistance);

      // Make it a message bubble
      overlay.messageBubble();

      var dom = overlay.data("MessageBubble").dom;
      dom.original.text(message.text);
      dom.translated.text(message.text_ja);
      dom.by.text("By " + message.author);
      //dom.from.text( "From: " + message.location );

      if (dom.by.text() == "By " || dom.by.text() == "By Your name" || dom.by.text() == "By 名前（ローマ字)") {
        dom.by.text("");
      }

      if (dom.from.text() == "From: " || dom.from.text() == "From: Your location" || dom.from.text() == "From: 地名（ローマ字)") {
        dom.from.text("");
      }

      overlay.data("MessageBubble").disappear(0);
      setTimeout(function() {
        overlay.data("MessageBubble").appear(250);
      }, 20);

      return overlay;
    }

    this.latLngPixel = function(latLng) {
      var projection = self.overlay.getProjection();
      return projection.fromLatLngToContainerPixel(latLng);
    }
  }

  JP.map = new Map();
})();

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', JP.map.init);
```

```css
html,
body,
#mapCanvas {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk"></script>
<div id="mapCanvas"></div>
```